# Firebase Push Notification not received when flutter app in foreground?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) for firebase push notifications. I received push notifications when app in background or app is forcefully closed but not received when app in foreground.

And Second issue is push notification show without app icon. Its shows blank square icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firebase doesn't  show push notifications when the app in foreground, So we need to configure the local notification for Firebase

Check this package

[Library for Local Notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

Comment: Do you mean onMessage() function where I am receiving the firebase push notification there I am firing local notifications

Comment: showInNotification(Map<String, dynamic> pushMessageMap) {
    if (pushMessageMap != null) {
      String messageInNotification = pushMessageMap["alert"];
      if (messageInNotification != null) {
        String notificationPayload = getPushMapToString(pushMessageMap);
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          0,
          'NAME',
          messageInNotification,
          platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: notificationPayload,
        );
      }
    }
  }

Comment: Yes  I used This Function in onMessage()

Comment: Can you tell me how to push a specific screen through a home screen when I tapped on push or local notification

Comment: I want to when I tapped on push notification open a specific screen of my app and then I tapped on back button show home screen of my app

Comment: Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new YourScreen()), ModalRoute.withName('/'));
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to push notifications and you have to use this following code,

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true
  );
```

in the main method.